# text-overflow: ellipsis with inline-block

Tags: css, ellipsis

I have the following html code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      span {
        display:inline-block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style='width:60px; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;
      text-overflow:ellipsis'>
      <span>abc</span> 
      <span>def</span> 
      <span>ghi</span> 
      <span>jkl</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result looks like:

> abc def g 
>   (the g is partially cropped)

Question) How can I make it looks like:

> abc def g...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is working in Firefox so I think it’s a bug in the webkit engine.

Comment: Confirmed working in Firefox. Setting all span elements with `display: inline-block` interferes in Chrome. Removing that fixes the issue in Chrome. Also, you'll need to increase the width of the div if you want to show the "g". The ellipsis takes up some of that space.